# Definitions of the module $R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty)$

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ac.commutative-algebra

There are several constructions of the [Prüfer group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pr%C3%BCfer_group) $\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty$; here are two that are relevant for this question.

1. It can be constructed via the short exact sequence
   $$
   0 \to \mathbb{Z} \to p^{-1} \mathbb{Z} \to \mathbb{Z}/p^\infty \to 0.
   $$
2. It can be constructed as the colimit $$\mathbb{Z}/p^\infty = \operatorname*{colim}_k\mathbb{Z}/p^k\mathbb{Z}$$
   where the homomorphisms are induced by multiplication by $p$.

It is not too hard to see that these are isomorphic.

There is a more complicated construction that often appears in topology. Now, let $R$ be a ring, and let $I = (x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})$ be a finitely-generated ideal inside of $R$, generated by a regular sequence. Then, there is an $R$-module $R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty)$, defined in the following way, by first inverting $x_i$ and taking the cokernel, i.e., by the short exact sequences
$$
0 \to R \to x_0^{-1}R \to R/(x_0^\infty) \to 0 \\
0 \to R/(x_0^\infty) \to x_1^{-1}R/(x_0^\infty) \to R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty) \to 0 \\
0 \to R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty) \to x_2^{-1}R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty) \to R/(x_0^\infty,x_1^\infty,x_2^\infty) \to 0 \\
 \cdots
$$

This is the analogue of construction (1) above.

I would like to propose a different construction, which is the analogue of (2). Let $I^k$ denote the $k$-th power of the ideal $I$. There is a system
$$
\cdots \subset I^k \subset I^{k-1} \subset \cdots 
$$
which gives maps
$$
\cdots \to R/I^k \to R/I^{k-1} \to \cdots 
$$

Now we work in the derived category, and let $DM = \mathbb{R}\text{Hom}_R(M,R)$ be the (derived) dual. The first claim is that $DR/I^k = \Sigma^{-n}R/I^k$. To see this, start with the cofiber sequence
$$
R \xrightarrow{x_0} R \to R/(x_0);
$$
this is self dual, and $DR/x_0 = \Sigma^{-1}R/(x_1)$. Induction using the cofiber sequences
$$
R/(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1}) \xrightarrow{x_i} R/(x_0,\ldots,x_{i-1}) \to R/(x_0,\ldots,x_i)
$$
proves the claim for $R/I$. For $R/I^k$ inductively use the cofiber sequences
$$
I^k/I^{k-1} \to R/I^k \to R/I^{k-1}
$$
and the fact that 
$$
\bigoplus_{k \ge 0} I^k/I^{k+1} = R/I[x_1,\ldots,x_n]
$$
to see inductively that $DR/I^k = \Sigma^{-n}R/I^k$.

Thus (after desuspension) we can get a sequence
$$
\cdots \to R/I^{k-1} \to R/I^k \to \cdots.
$$

Define $R/I^\infty$ to be the colimit of this system.

My question is the following:

> Is $R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty) \simeq R/I^\infty$?

Here is an idea of how to prove this. Firstly, I believe one can show, by a cofinality argument, that
$$
R/I^\infty = \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{n-1}^i).
$$

(Here I mean the colimit over the system of ideals  $I_t = (x_0^t,\ldots,x_{n-1}^t)$).

Then to prove the claim note that it is clear that $R/(x_1^\infty) = \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i)$. Then inductively we have
$$
R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{k}^\infty )= \operatorname{colim}_j(R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{k-1}^\infty)/x_k^j) \\
= \operatorname{colim}_j(\operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{k-1}^i)/x_k^j) \\
= \operatorname{colim}_j \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{k-1}^i,x_k^j) \\
= \operatorname{colim}_i R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{k-1}^i,x_k^i)
$$

By induction this should give the result, I hope.

Disclaimer: I originally [asked](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1310761/definitions-of-the-ring-r-x-0-infty-ldots-x-n-1-infty) this on math.se, but did not get a response.

Comment: The first construction is problematic if $x_0,\dots, x_k$ is not a regular sequence.

Comment: @FernandoMuro: Yes, the sequence $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ is assumed to be regular

Comment: Are the maps of the direct system $R/I_t\rightarrow R/I_{t+1}$ the maps induced by the multiplication with $x_0\ldots x_{n-1}$ (the direct system whose colimit $R/I^\infty$)? If so, I guess that your question has a positive answer.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly guess that, you mean,  the maps of your direct system, $$R/I_t\rightarrow R/I_{t+1},$$ whose colimit is, $$R/I^\infty,$$ are the multiplication by $x_0\ldots x_{n-1}$. So I think that your question has a positive answer. For a complete description I aim to firstly give some definitions. The following definitions  are given in the paper [Sharp and Zakeri](http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6967552).

Let $R$ be a ring and $U$ be a non-empty subset of $R^n$ where $n\in \mathbb{N}$. Then $U $ is said to be a traingular subset of $R^n$ if it satisfies the following two conditions:

(1) for each $(u_1,\ldots,u_n)\in U$ and $\alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_n\in \mathbb{N}$ we have $(u_1^{\alpha_1},\ldots,u_n^{\alpha_n})\in U$

(2) for each $(u_1,\ldots,u_n),(v_1,\ldots,v_n)\in U$ there exists $n\times n$ lower triangular matrices $H,K$ with entries in R and $(w_1,\ldots,w_n)\in U$ such that $H[u_1,\ldots,u_n]^\tau=[w_1,\ldots,w_n]^\tau=K[v_1,\ldots,v_n]^\tau$ (here the notation $\tau$ stands for the transpose of matrix).

Now fix a triangular subset $U$ of $R^n$. Let $M$ be an $R$-module. Then one can define an equivalance relation on $U\times M$ such that $((u_1,\ldots,u_n),m)$ is equivalent to $((v_1,\ldots v_n),n)$  if and only if there exists $(w_1,\ldots,w_n)\in U$ and lower triangular matrices $H,K$ such that, $$ H[u_1,\ldots,u_n]^\tau=[w_1,\ldots,w_n]^\tau=K[v_1,\ldots,v_n]^\tau $$ and $\text{det}(H)m-\text{det}(K)n\in (w_1,\ldots,w_{n-1})M$.

By this definition we get an $R$-module denote by $U^{-n}(M)$ which is called the module of generalized fractions. In fact one can verify that this definition generalizes the definition of the localization of an $R$-module at a multiplicative closed subset of $R$.

Now assume that $x_1,\ldots,x_n$ is sequence of elements of $R$. Extend this sequence to an infinite sequence, $x_1,\ldots,x_n,1,1,\ldots,1,\ldots$ ($x_i=1$ for $i\ge n+1$). Then for each $i$ we get the triangular subset, $$U_i:=\{(x_1^{\alpha_1},\ldots,x_i^{\alpha_i});\text{ for some } 0\le j\le i, \alpha_1,\ldots,\alpha_j\in \mathbb{N} \text{ and }  ,\alpha_{j+1}=\ldots=\alpha_i=0\},$$ of $R^i$. In particular for each $1\le i\le n$ we get the $R$-module $U_i^{-i}(R)$ of generalized fractions which form the complex,
  $$ 0\rightarrow R\rightarrow U_1^{-1}(R)\rightarrow \ldots \rightarrow U_i^{-i}(R) \overset{e^i}{\rightarrow}U_{i+1}^{-i-1}(R)\rightarrow\ldots,$$
in which the differential $e^i$ are defined by,

$$ e^i(r/(u_1,\ldots,u_i))=r/(u_1,\ldots,u_i,1).$$

In 2.2 Theorem of the paper [On the Generalized Fractions of Sharp and Zakeri](http://jlms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-28/3/417.full.pdf) it is proved the above complex is isomorphic to the complex which is the same as your first construction, i.e. considering the  cokernel of the localization map at element $x_i$ at each step.

Now in your situation we have the sequence $x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1}$ and the above mentioned Theorem states that $U_{n+1}^{-n-1}(R)\cong R/(x_0^\infty,\ldots,x_{n-1}^\infty)$ (with your notation).
  Now one can  prove that the module of generalized fractions $U^{-n-1}_{n+1}(R)$ is nothing but your direct limit $\lim_{\rightarrow} R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{n-1}^i)$ in which the maps $R/(x_0^i,\ldots,x_{n-1}^i)\rightarrow R/(x_0^j,\ldots,x_{n-1}^j)$ are multiplication maps by $x_0^{j-i}\ldots x_{n-1}^{j-i}$  (In order to prove this isomorphism you need to use Lemma 2.3 of the paper [Modules of Generalized Fractions](http://journals.cambridge.org.sci-hub.org/action/displayAbstract?fromPage=online&aid=6967552). Using this lemma you can reduce an arbitrary lower triangular matrix to a diagonal matrix whose diagonal is something like $x_0^t,\ldots,x_{n-1}^t,1$)). In fact your question has still an affirmative answer even if we drop the condition for the sequence to be a regular sequence. The modules you are interested are called the top local cohomology modules supported at the ideal $(x_0,\ldots,x_{n-1})$.

By virtue of the paper [Comparison of Certain Complexes of Modules of Generalized Fractions and Čech Complexes](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/00927870701509586), over a Noetherian ring, it is always possible even to compute also the  other local cohomology modules by means of the above complex.

Comment: @Drew Heard, You are welcome. Was the answer satisfactory? I asked because you didn't approve it. By the way, I would be so delighted if you could possibly please describe, briefly, the topological view of your question, if it has a topological view.

Comment: I've kept it open in the hope that someone comes along and tells me that the sketch I outlined in the question is correct! I'm still working through the answer you gave; it has quite a few references to sort through. There is a topological nature to the question, which unfortunately I cannot adequately describe in the comments.